# Minimize Euclidean distance from sets of points in 3-d

Tags: algorithm, geometry, projection

Let's look at four (m) points in 3-d space- I want to generalize to n-d, but 3 should suffice for a solution ( Part 1).

```
a= (x1, y1, z1)

b= (x2, y2, z2)

c= (x3, y3, z3)
.
.

p= (x , y , z)

Find point q = c1* a + c2* b + c3* c + ..

where c1 + c2 + c3 +.. = 1
and  c1, c2, c3, .. >= 0
s.t.
euclidean distance pq is minimized.
```

### What algorithms can be used ? Idea or pseudocode is enough.

Part 2: solve for m points in n-dimensions :

I thought it would be trivial to generalize to m points in n dimensions, but turns out it is not straightforward. I created another problem for the general problem here: [minimize euclidean distance from sets of points in n-dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52134596/minimize-euclidean-distance-from-sets-of-points-in-n-dimensions]])

Comment: 1) `x1+x2+x3` is a scalar, not a vector. Perhaps you meant `(x1,x2,x3)`. 2)This is more of a math question than a programming question. [mathematics.se] would be a better fit  3) Let `f(c1,c2,c3) = (d(p,q))^2`. Find the gradient of `f` and set it equal to zero.

Comment: Thanks, vectors edited. Added condition.

Comment: Is the equation `c1 + c2 + c3 = 1` the only condition on `c1,c2,c3`? If so, if the points `a,b,c` are not collinear then point `q` can be any point in the plane defined by `a,b,c`. If those points are collinear but not identical then point `q` can be any point on the line defined by the points. If those points are identical then `q` is only that point. Are you sure there are not the additional conditions that `c1>=0`, `c2>=0`, `c3>=0`? Those would restrict `q` to the triangular region made by points `a,b,c`. All this should point you to a solution.

Comment: Assuming that you are assuming that the `c_i` are positive, you are asking for the the point `q` on the *convex hull* of the given points. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2146961/294695) on [mathematics.se]. Coding it by hand would be burdensome (especially in higher dimensions as you seem to want to do) but any good quadratic programming library could handle this easily.

Comment: Thank you,  updated again: c1, c2, c3 >= 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question in 3D can be reduced to a simple affine 2D geometry problem by projecting the point `P` on the plane defined by the three points `A, B, C`, or the two vectors `AB` and `AC` (or another combinations of `AB, AC, and BC`).

At first sight, it seems likely that the 3+1 points problem generalizes to N dimensions (3 points always defining a triangle and a plane).
However, it is not immediately clear if this approach would work for more points that would not be coplanar.

1- reduction to 2D by projecting `P` to a point `P'`on the plane defined by vectors `AB`, and `AC`.

2- understand that the position of `P'` is determined by only one coefficient `t in the Reals` s.t. `P'` is an affine combination of `AB` and `AC`  :
`P' = t * AB + (1-t) * AC`

3- from there, `P'` can be in 3 distinct locations:

- (a) inside the triangle `ABC`: in that case, `Q = P'`
- (b) in the areas delimited by an orthogonal outwards projection of
  one of the segments; in that case `Q` is the orthogonal projection of
  `P'` on the closest segment.
- (c) not in (a) or (b); in that last trivial case, `Q` is the closest
  of `A, B, or C`

---

[image]

Comment: Not sure I follow.  Let's say:
a = (0, 0, 0 )
b=  (2, 0, 0)
c=  (0, 2, 0)
p = (1, 1, 1)
Here, I think  p' = (1, 1, 0 ) = q and dist(pq) = 1. Somehow you would put q on the boundary. 
Also, I should update, I would like a solution with m points (e.g. a, b, c, d....) and p

Comment: Yes, you are correct, in your example `P' =(1, 1, 0)`, and `Q =(1, 1, 0)`, and `distance(PQ) = 1`. You should not change a question that explicitly states "four points", and "3 (dimensions) should suffice for a solution", to new requirements with m points and n dimensions. (but you could, of course, ask a new question that builds on this one)

Comment: your point: "[P'] inside the triangle ABC; in that case, Q is the point on either segments AB, AC, or BC". - could you address/edit that?
Also, if we add another point, D, still in 3-dimensions your solution would throw out the point that does not fall on the face (not plane) closest to P ( how would you define that? )- for P outside the shape, reducing it to your current solution.

Comment: `P'` inside `ABC`: you project `P'` on each of the segments `AB, AC, BC`, Q is the point on the closest segment.

Comment: But as in my example above, P' is inside ABC however Q is not on one of the segments, but on the inside.

Comment: Adding a fourth point `D` not coplanar to `ABC` complicates matters; you now have 4 planes describing a tetrahedron. You can probably repeat this approach on each of the planes, find 4 points `Q`, then choose the closest to `P`, but there might be a better approach, IDK.

Comment: In your example in the comments, `Q = (1, 1, 0)` is on the segment `BC`.

Comment: say A= (0, 0, 0) B= (200, 0,0), C= (0, 200, 0). Q is still (1, 1, 0), but clearly not on line segment BC. no?

Comment: Actually, `P'` the projection of `P` on the plane `ABC` is at `(1, 1, 0)`, as I understood, `Q` is the closest projection of `P'` on the segments `AB, AC, BC`... if I misunderstood that part, then `Q = P'`, solved without further processing.

Comment: for P' inside ABC, P' = Q always I think

Comment: Yes, `P'` is the closest point on the surface to `P`, your problem statement was maybe a bit ambiguous on that part.

Comment: For P' inside (including boundary) ABC, P' = Q always I think, you should edit your answer so I can accept it. Thank you. Although, now I realize it's not trivial to generalize this to m points and n dimensions. I thought this would suffice. I was wrong.  Do you mind if I edit the question to ask for the answer in two steps and I can accept your answer as  solution to first part and leave it open?

Comment: ok, I am glad we eventually understood each other. I will edit my answer so `P'=Q` when `P'` lays inside `ABC`. You should probably ask a new question for the more general case though, linking to this one if you wish.

Comment: I think it is helpful to have this for the second part. Your figure is good too you should keep it. I will reword to say part 1 and 2, you could just add one line on the top saying " solution to part 1"

Comment: I linked a new question (part 2), you do not need to add comment, but I think the figure was good. Also, this got -2 votes: an upvote would help. Thank you.